# How can I store the row and column numbers of a range in vba, and why am I getting a 438 runtime error?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to capture the row and column numbers of a ranger in variables.

After a fair amount of googling, it seems I might have to store these as Longs and not Integers, but not sure.  Either way I get the same "438 object doesn't support this property or method" error when I reach the line "r1 = wb.ws1.Range("CI14").Row" as below.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("test.xlsm")
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Worksheet1")

Dim r1 As Long
r1 = wb.ws1.Range("CI14").Row
Dim c1 As Long
c1 = wb.ws1.Range("CI14").Column
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = wb.ws1.Cells(r1, c1)
```

I am trying to get something I can iterate on in a while loop, like so:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(rng1.Value)
    (conditional statement)
    r1 = r1 + 1
    Set rng1 = wb.ws1.Cells(r1, c1)
Loop
```

Comment: You already `set ws1=wb.worksheets("Worksheet1")`.  So when you try to execute the `r1=` line, and expand the `ws1` portion, you would get `r1= wb.wb.worksheets("Worksheet1").Range ...`   Note that the `wb.wb` portion is not valid.

Comment: And you do have to use the Long data type since Integers only go as high as `2^15-1` and there can be many more rows than that.

Answer (score 0):

`ws1` is an object, it is not a Method or Property of your `wb` object.

The correct syntax is:

```
r1 = ws1.Range("CI14").Row
```